# how to handle transation roll back exception in spring?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, cypher

What I want is quite simple: validation for a node id.

The project structure is:
Controller(endpoint) - Service - DAO. @transaction in Service layer, validation in Service layer as well.

In endpoint, pass in DTO object. Validate node id in service layer and save to neo4j database in DAO layer. In the DTO object(e.g.Student) I pass in the other node ID(e.g.Class) which is used to set up student and class relationship. Before saving, I do validation for the node(Class) id.

If I use `repository.findOne(id)` and  pass in node ID which exist in database but wrong type. This will raise: `org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: '__type__' property not found for RelationshipImpl #10118 of type 36 between Node[7054] and Node[6726]` which will lead to the following exception:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Failed to commit, transaction rolledback
```

If I use following query and pass in node id which does not exist in database

```
start node1 = node(id)
return node1
```

org.neo4j.cypher.EntityNotFoundException will be raised and lead to UnexpectedRollbackException as well.

Is there any way I catch these exceptions and return null or false without UnexpectedRollbackException?

Or is there any way I can check Node id exists in database easily?

Comment: 01) Confuse your "requirement", would you share the method declaration, the one with @Transactional, who is throwing the exception? 02) You are receiving a null object or an exception?

Comment: Perhaps you can share a bit more of your code? You can use `repository.findOne(id)`  for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix this by using:

1. For Node:

   ```
           Node node = neo4jTemplate.getNode(id);
           String type = (String) node.getProperty("__type__");
           if (!type.equals(nodeClass.getName())) {
               throw new ResultNotFoundException("No such object (" + nodeClass.getSimpleName() + ": id=" + id + ") in database");
           }
           return neo4jTemplate.projectTo(node, nodeClass);
   ```
2. For Relationship

   ```
           Relationship relationship = neo4jTemplate.getRelationship(id);
           String type = (String) relationship.getProperty("__type__");
           if (!type.equals(nodeClass.getName())) {
               throw new ResultNotFoundException("No such object (" + nodeClass.getSimpleName() + ": id=" + id + ") in database");
           }
           return neo4jTemplate.projectTo(relationship, nodeClass);
   ```